# CSS not loading on Chrome for drupal site after moving to https

Tags: migrations

I have a Drupal site which has huge content. Recently I moved my dev content on production and also changed the site URL from http to https.
The problem is that the site is working fine on all browser except Google Chrome.
It is not loading the CSS. I can see the content but its without CSS.

I have the same setup for dev site and production site but still it is not showing any css.
If anybody has a solution please let me know.

Also I am using the same theme for dev and production.
In the site information it is showing the following message:

> This page includes other resources which are not secure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warning which you see is because some of the contents are not secure, which means they are fetched using `http` instead of `https`.
As per the limited information provided by you, I'd suggest you to follow the following steps:

- Inspect the source code of the page, by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>, in Chrome.
- Check to see if there are links present in the content(specially the `<head>` section) are using the pattern `http://...` instead of `https`.
- Find the resources (css/js/images) which are loaded using `http`.
- Identify which part of the site (module or a theme function) adds that resource.
- Make the necessary changes to make sure the resources are loaded securely i.e. via `https`.

Answer (score 2):

One possible answer is that you have your `$base_url` in settings.php set to something like `http://www.example.com`. Try commenting out that line or changing `http://` to `https://`.